# <code> tag adds extra line when wrapped in <pre> tag

Tags: html, frontend, prismjs

I'm sorry if this seems rather basic, but I've already tried several suggestions and they didn't seem to work.

I'm trying to display a code snippet so I wrapped the contents in a `<code>` tag which is inside a `<pre>` tag. Note that I styled this using PrismJS.

```html
<pre class="line-numbers">
  <code class="language-html">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
  &lt;meta charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot; content=&quot;IE=edge&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;/head&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

The problem is that the DOCTYPE appears on the second line. I think this is because the `<code>` tag is considered its own line, but I'm not sure how to fix this.
[Code Snippet display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBong.png)
[Dev Tools](https://imgur.com/a/O2JvrhZ)

When I put the first line on the same line as the `<code>` opening tag, the blank space disapppeared, however the doctype is pushed back due to preformatting.

```html
<pre class="line-numbers">
  <code class="language-html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
```

[Modified snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFHFb.png)
I did the same thing for the closing tags as well and it removed the trailing empty line: `&lt;/html&gt;</code></pre>`
So I think it's because the `<code>` tag includes itself.

I've already tried removing margin, padding, or any unnecessary whitespace but it didn't seem to do anything. Also, PrismJS will only work if the opening `<code>` tag is on the following line of `<pre>` and indented:

```html
<pre>
  <code>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on the PrismJS [Github](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism), I discovered that they have a Normalize Whitespace plugin that trims all leading and trailing whitespace in a code block. It seems this is the [official solution](https://prismjs.com/plugins/normalize-whitespace/) to this issue. I pasted the modifications into my existing prismJS file and linked the plugin in this answer.

Since I originally modified my prismCSS file to adjust to this issue, after adopting the new JS plugin, return all alignments to the default settings, in case line numbers and highlighting don't show up after the fix.

```js
!(function () {
  if ("undefined" != typeof Prism) {
    var e =
        Object.assign ||
        function (e, t) {
          for (var n in t) t.hasOwnProperty(n) && (e[n] = t[n]);
          return e;
        },
      t = {
        "remove-trailing": "boolean",
        "remove-indent": "boolean",
        "left-trim": "boolean",
        "right-trim": "boolean",
        "break-lines": "number",
        indent: "number",
        "remove-initial-line-feed": "boolean",
        "tabs-to-spaces": "number",
        "spaces-to-tabs": "number",
      };
    (n.prototype = {
      setDefaults: function (t) {
        this.defaults = e(this.defaults, t);
      },
      normalize: function (t, n) {
        for (var r in (n = e(this.defaults, n))) {
          var i = r.replace(/-(\w)/g, function (e, t) {
            return t.toUpperCase();
          });
          "normalize" !== r &&
            "setDefaults" !== i &&
            n[r] &&
            this[i] &&
            (t = this[i].call(this, t, n[r]));
        }
        return t;
      },
      leftTrim: function (e) {
        return e.replace(/^\s+/, "");
      },
      rightTrim: function (e) {
        return e.replace(/\s+$/, "");
      },
      tabsToSpaces: function (e, t) {
        return (t = 0 | t || 4), e.replace(/\t/g, new Array(++t).join(" "));
      },
      spacesToTabs: function (e, t) {
        return (t = 0 | t || 4), e.replace(RegExp(" {" + t + "}", "g"), "\t");
      },
      removeTrailing: function (e) {
        return e.replace(/\s*?$/gm, "");
      },
      removeInitialLineFeed: function (e) {
        return e.replace(/^(?:\r?\n|\r)/, "");
      },
      removeIndent: function (e) {
        var t = e.match(/^[^\S\n\r]*(?=\S)/gm);
        return t && t[0].length
          ? (t.sort(function (e, t) {
              return e.length - t.length;
            }),
            t[0].length ? e.replace(RegExp("^" + t[0], "gm"), "") : e)
          : e;
      },
      indent: function (e, t) {
        return e.replace(
          /^[^\S\n\r]*(?=\S)/gm,
          new Array(++t).join("\t") + "$&"
        );
      },
      breakLines: function (e, t) {
        t = !0 === t ? 80 : 0 | t || 80;
        for (var n = e.split("\n"), i = 0; i < n.length; ++i)
          if (!(r(n[i]) <= t)) {
            for (
              var o = n[i].split(/(\s+)/g), a = 0, l = 0;
              l < o.length;
              ++l
            ) {
              var s = r(o[l]);
              (a += s) > t && ((o[l] = "\n" + o[l]), (a = s));
            }
            n[i] = o.join("");
          }
        return n.join("\n");
      },
    }),
      "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = n),
      (Prism.plugins.NormalizeWhitespace = new n({
        "remove-trailing": !0,
        "remove-indent": !0,
        "left-trim": !0,
        "right-trim": !0,
      })),
      Prism.hooks.add("before-sanity-check", function (e) {
        var n = Prism.plugins.NormalizeWhitespace;
        if (
          (!e.settings || !1 !== e.settings["whitespace-normalization"]) &&
          Prism.util.isActive(e.element, "whitespace-normalization", !0)
        )
          if ((e.element && e.element.parentNode) || !e.code) {
            var r = e.element.parentNode;
            if (e.code && r && "pre" === r.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
              for (var i in (null == e.settings && (e.settings = {}), t))
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(t, i)) {
                  var o = t[i];
                  if (r.hasAttribute("data-" + i))
                    try {
                      var a = JSON.parse(r.getAttribute("data-" + i) || "true");
                      typeof a === o && (e.settings[i] = a);
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
              for (
                var l = r.childNodes, s = "", c = "", u = !1, m = 0;
                m < l.length;
                ++m
              ) {
                var f = l[m];
                f == e.element
                  ? (u = !0)
                  : "#text" === f.nodeName &&
                    (u ? (c += f.nodeValue) : (s += f.nodeValue),
                    r.removeChild(f),
                    --m);
              }
              if (e.element.children.length && Prism.plugins.KeepMarkup) {
                var d = s + e.element.innerHTML + c;
                (e.element.innerHTML = n.normalize(d, e.settings)),
                  (e.code = e.element.textContent);
              } else
                (e.code = s + e.code + c),
                  (e.code = n.normalize(e.code, e.settings));
            }
          } else e.code = n.normalize(e.code, e.settings);
      });
  }
  function n(t) {
    this.defaults = e({}, t);
  }
  function r(e) {
    for (var t = 0, n = 0; n < e.length; ++n)
      e.charCodeAt(n) == "\t".charCodeAt(0) && (t += 3);
    return e.length + t;
  }
})();
```